# Identity concerning Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry

Is this identity true for a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and its Levi-Civita connection? Any idea on how to prove/disprove it?
\begin{align}
 g(\nabla_XV,Y)=g(X,\nabla_YV)
\end{align}
for $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing this in local coordinates? And assume the metric is flat (so all of the Christoffel symbols vanish).

Comment: If the vector field $V$ happens to be the gradient of some scalar function $f$, then yes, it is true, see [A computation for null vector fields in general relativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4582150/568204), and the reason is due to metric compatibility, and also symmetry of the Hessian (which is due to torsion freeness of the Levi-Civita connection).

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, in general. What can be said is the following: $$g(\nabla_XV,Y)-g(X,\nabla_YV)=\big(\operatorname{d}V^\flat\big)(X,Y),$$ where $\flat:TM\to T^*M$ is "musical isomorphism" given by contraction with the metric, $V^\flat:=g(V,\cdot)$.

Indeed, the computation in local coordinates gives $$g(\nabla_XV,Y)-g(X,\nabla_YV)=\nabla_aV_b\,X^aY^b-\nabla_bV_a\,X^aY^b$$ and using the symmetry of the connection you find the above expression.

So, the identity you are looking for holds for every two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ if and only if $g(V,\cdot)$ is a closed $1$-form.