# Eikonal equation and Geodesic flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am reading some context from computer graphics about using eikonal equation to compute geodesics on triangular mesh, I find some reference e.g [text](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0019357718304294)

The authors state that if $\| \text{grad} \: \textit{f} \ \|_g=1$ then we get $$\nabla_{\text{grad} \: \textit{f}} \ \text{grad} \: \textit{f}=0$$

Could anyone provide a proof of this statement or point me to a reference where this is proven?

Comment: Hint: When $X$ is a vector field of constant length and the connection is metric compatible then $0=\nabla(X^iX_i)$ from which you should deduce
$$
0=X_i\nabla X^i\,.
$$
Then apply this to $X=\operatorname{grad}f\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. This only proves that $\mathrm{grad} f \perp \nabla_{\mathrm{grad}f} \mathrm{grad}f$, right?

Comment: @Didier $Y_i\nabla X^i$ is the covariant directional derivative of $X$ in the direction of $Y\,.$ In other notation this is $\nabla_Y\,X\,.$ So I believe it proves OP's equation. OOPS. No. I think I was wrong. Will think about it.

Comment: If $\alpha(t)$ is an integral curve of $\operatorname{grad} f$ and $\alpha (0) = p$, then $\nabla _{\operatorname{grad}f}\operatorname{grad}f  (p)= \nabla_{\alpha'(0)} \alpha'$. I don't see why the term on the right hand side is zero, this is true only if $\alpha$ is a geodesic.

Comment: [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331109353_Geodesic_vector_fields_and_Eikonal_equation_on_a_Riemannian_manifold) is a more accessible version of the paper.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4582150/568204). The key thing is you have to exploit symmetry of the Hessian of functions (due to the Levi-Civita connection being torsion-free), i.e you can’t just think of $L:=\text{grad}(f)$ as an abstract vector field; you need the fact that it comes from a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $X$ is the gradient of a function $f$ then $X$ is rotation free:
$$\tag{1}
\nabla_\ell X_k=\nabla_k X_\ell.
$$
The eikonal equation can be written as
$$
(\nabla_\ell f)(\nabla^\ell f)=g^{\ell i}(\nabla_\ell f)(\nabla_if)=1\,.
$$
Assuming that $\nabla$ is metric compatible we can differentiate and get
\begin{align}
0&=g^{\ell i}(\nabla_k\nabla_\ell f)(\nabla_i f)+g^{\ell i}(\nabla_\ell f)(\nabla_k\nabla_if)
\stackrel{(1)}=g^{\ell i}(\nabla_\ell\nabla_k f)(\nabla_i f)+g^{\ell i}(\nabla_\ell f)(\nabla_i\nabla_kf)\\[2mm]
&=(\nabla^i\nabla_kf)(\nabla_if)+(\nabla_\ell f)(\nabla^\ell\nabla_kf)=2(\nabla_if)\nabla^i\nabla_kf\,.
\end{align}
which can be written as the directional derivative of $X=\nabla f$ with respect to itself:
$$
0=\nabla_XX\,.
$$
This shows that $\nabla f$ is geodesic when it is eikonal.